# Layout issues when adding toolbar to preference fragment

Tags: android, android-layout

I try to built a preference screen with a toolbar, but I got some issues:

[image]

- The status bar is white. I want it to look like my main screen (same theme). Somehow it does not apply the color
- The toolbar overlays the content. I tried a a layout_marginTop on the list view, but it does not change anything.

Here is the code of my activity_settings.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"
        app:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the AndroidManifest entry:

```
<activity
    android:name=".activities.SettingsActivity"
    android:label="@string/activity_settings"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"` to your ListView in the xml.

Replace `fill_parent` with `match_parent` it's deprecated. 
Remove `android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"` it's not working in `LinearLayout`

Comment: `I tried a layout_marginTop on the list view, but it does not change anything.`

Comment: I also tried the things in the "edit" part, but does not change anything sadly...